Bayes theorem helps win World War II
Has anyone read this article (https://towardsdatascience.com/how-bayes-theorem-helped-win-the-second-world-war-7f3be5f4676c), or are solidly familiar with the exactly how Bayes theorem helped with WWII.  This is the "best" article I can find illustrating to SOME extent how it is used, but they let the readers "fill in the blanks" and having read this about a dozen times, I am hoping for some help.  This is the part of the article I am really struggling with.

The allied forces already had knowledge of part of the Japanese code book, and many of the code groups were known. These were referred to as “good groups” and were tabulated along with their (non-carrying) differences (V). If 50 groups were known, 1225 differences had to be calculated and recorded.
Cryptoanalysts would compare the differences calculated from the intercepted messages and those from good groups. If a match was found (in our case 22571, shown in red), a hypothetical additive was calculated (shown in green).
The final and most important task was to test this hypothetical additive for its validity. As a first step, the additive was subtracted from its corresponding encoded word in every message (VI). If the resulting code (shown in blue) broke the “divisible by 3” rule, the additive could be quickly discarded, saving the Allies a large amount of time. Usually, multiple potential additives would pass this test and hence statistical analysis was used to determine their relative strengths.

Can anybody give a detailed explanation for this part in particular?  I find it fascinating, and yet the calculations are extremely rare, if not impossible to find.  I would be forever grateful   Thanks

I agree this is a great story, thanks for pointing it out. Did you read the E. Simpson's paper, it's open access & I find it easier to follow that the Medium post: Edward Simpson, Edward Simpson: Bayes at Bletchley Park, Significance, Volume 7, Issue 2, June 2010, Pages 76–80, https://doi.org/10.1111/j.1740-9713.2010.00424.x PS. This is the Simpson of Simpson's paradox!

The “German tank problem” may interest readers who like the intersection here of statistics and World War Two history.

Thanks for pointing out German tank problem, I am going to read Simpsons paper.  for some reason, I could not find it until recently.   I will take a look at the German tank problem also.   Was not familiar with it
